# UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U18'), dtype('int64')) -> None

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I want to create a stacked bar chart using plotly based on the frequency of each feature with respect to the subtypes in `admin.disease_code`.
My code raised `UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U18'), dtype('int64')) -> None` error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
```

Grouping and aggregation

```
agg_df = df.groupby(["admin.disease_code"]).agg({'count'})
agg_df = agg_df.drop("tcga_id", axis=1)
agg_df.columns = agg_df.columns.get_level_values(0)
agg_df.rename(columns = {'patient.days_to_death':'days_to_death', 'patient.vital_status':'vital_status', 'patient.age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis':'age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis', 'patient.gender':'gender','patient.karnofsky_performance_score':'karnofsky_performance_score'}, inplace = True)
```

Stacked bar plot

```
fig = px.bar(agg_df, x=agg_df.columns, title="Clinical information for RCC subtypes")
fig.show()
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/79231555.py in <module>
----> 1 fig = px.bar(agg_df, x=agg_df.columns, title="Clinical information for RCC subtypes")
      2 fig.show()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/express/_chart_types.py in bar(data_frame, x, y, color, pattern_shape, facet_row, facet_col, facet_col_wrap, facet_row_spacing, facet_col_spacing, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, text, base, error_x, error_x_minus, error_y, error_y_minus, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, color_continuous_scale, pattern_shape_sequence, pattern_shape_map, range_color, color_continuous_midpoint, opacity, orientation, barmode, log_x, log_y, range_x, range_y, text_auto, title, template, width, height)
    375         constructor=go.Bar,
    376         trace_patch=dict(textposition="auto"),
--> 377         layout_patch=dict(barmode=barmode),
    378     )
    379 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   1988     apply_default_cascade(args)
   1989 
-> 1990     args = build_dataframe(args, constructor)
   1991     if constructor in [go.Treemap, go.Sunburst, go.Icicle] and args["path"] is not None:
   1992         args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in build_dataframe(args, constructor)
   1457             value_vars=wide_value_vars,
   1458             var_name=var_name,
-> 1459             value_name=value_name,
   1460         )
   1461         assert len(df_output.columns) == len(set(df_output.columns)), (

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in melt(self, id_vars, value_vars, var_name, value_name, col_level, ignore_index)
   8344             value_name=value_name,
   8345             col_level=col_level,
-> 8346             ignore_index=ignore_index,
   8347         )
   8348 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/melt.py in melt(frame, id_vars, value_vars, var_name, value_name, col_level, ignore_index)
    142         mdata[col] = id_data
    143 
--> 144     mcolumns = id_vars + var_name + [value_name]
    145 
    146     # error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "ndarray",

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U18'), dtype('int64')) -> None
```

Data:

`df.head().to_dict()`

```
{'admin.disease_code': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11D-A381-01': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11D-A381-01': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A-11D-A381-01': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A-12D-A381-01': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A-21D-A381-01': 'kirp'},
 'patient.days_to_death': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11D-A381-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11D-A381-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A-11D-A381-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A-12D-A381-01': '1771',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A-21D-A381-01': nan},
 'patient.age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11D-A381-01': '53',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11D-A381-01': '71',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A-11D-A381-01': '71',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A-12D-A381-01': '67',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A-21D-A381-01': '80'},
 'patient.karnofsky_performance_score': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11D-A381-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11D-A381-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A-11D-A381-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A-12D-A381-01': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A-21D-A381-01': nan},
 'tcga_id': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11D-A381-01': 'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11D-A381-01': 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A-11D-A381-01': 'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A-12D-A381-01': 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A-21D-A381-01': 'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A'},
 'survival': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11D-A381-01': 'lts',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11D-A381-01': 'lts',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A-11D-A381-01': 'lts',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A-12D-A381-01': 'non-lts',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A-21D-A381-01': 'lts'}}
```

Data types
`agg_df.dtypes`

```
0
patient.days_to_death                          int64
patient.age_at_initial_pathologic_diagnosis    int64
patient.karnofsky_performance_score            int64
survival                                       int64
dtype: object
```

Expected output (example only):
[image]